# ng-repeat not rendering in google app engine view

Tags: html, angularjs, google-app-engine, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an app that is working fine on localhost, but when I deploy on google app engine `<tr ng-repeat="somestuff">` is being commented out in the browser:

[image: ng-0repeat commenting out]

Code from index.html:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="account in onlineAccounts | orderBy: 'currency'">
  <td><a ng-if="account.account_type=='offline'" class="delete-account-link" ng-click="deleteAccount(account.currency, account.location)">delete </a>{{account.currency}}</td>
  <td class="hidden-xs">{{account.balance | number : 3}}</td>
  <td class="hidden-xs">{{account.price_btc | number : 5}}</td>
  <td>{{account.price_usd | currency: '$':3}}</td>
  <td class="hidden-xs">{{account.total_btc | number : 2}}</td>
  <td ng-class="{change_loss: account.change_24h < 0, change_win: account.change_24h > 0}">{{account.change_24h}}%</td>
  <td ng-class="{change_loss: account.change_24h < 0, change_win: account.change_24h > 0}">{{account.total_usd * account.change_24h / 100 | currency}}</td>
  <td>{{account.total_usd | currency}}</td>
  <td class="hidden-xs">{{account.location}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is puzzling to me since it's rendering fine when running locally. Also, there are some other angular variables rendering ok.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: When the `ngRepeat` is generated AngularJS add comments like the one you get `<!-- ngRepeat : ... --!>` So this comment is not an error or a problem. If you inspect the elements in the example given at the end of [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) there are the same king of comments

Comment: Need more code. What is `onlineAccounts`? Show that code